# Showing that no roots of a certain 5th degree polynomial can be written as a sum of cube roots of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

> Let $f(x) = x^5 +4x^3 +3x^2+2x +7$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ be a real root of $f$. Show that there do not exist a positive integer $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and rational numbers $a_1,\dots,a_r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $$\alpha = \sqrt[3]{a_1} + \cdots + \sqrt[3]{a_r}$$

I've already shown that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ (maybe it is not useful, but at least it was to show that in the previous part of the question). How can I go from here?

Comment: But $5$  not divided by $3$.

Comment: In fact, the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $S_5$, so it is not solvable by radical anyway. Although I don't know a more direct proof of the problem.

Comment: Now, you just show there is no integer solution.